# Can things hope?

Tags: grammar, jlpt, subjects

This sentence in my JLPT book is explaining the nuance of `映{は}える`, but actually it's the use of `ほしい` that's a puzzling me a bit:

> このピンクのスカーフが映{は}える服{ふく}を選{えら}んでほしい。

This is saying that the pink scarf would go with some very flashy clothes.

What I'm not clear on though, is if it is the speaker saying that they would like to choose some flashy clothes to go with the pink scarf. In other words, it's the speaker who is doing the `ほしい`.

Or, is it that the pink scarf itself is simply more suited to going with flashy clothes? Similar to how in English I could say, "this pink scarf cries out for more flashy clothes to go with it." In other words, it is the scarf doing the `ほしい`.

So is it the scarf or the speaker that the `ほしい` part of the sentence refers to?

Comment: Please check the construct [verb]てほしい such as 選んでほしい and 歌ってほしい.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That sentence means "I want you to choose clothes which resonate with this pink scarf."

After the te-form of a verb, `ほしい` means "I want (you) to do something" according to Edict.